# List of issues using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm working a jQuery script for a responsive mobile nav on my Wordpress site. I've set it so that my nav menu is positioned to the right, and when I click the button, it slides left and the html tag moves with it.

There are a few issues I'm having with this script, I'm probably missing something here.

First of all, the menu button only allows me to open and close the menu once, then it starts closing itself automatically every time I click it until I refresh the page.

Secondly, if I have my mobile menu open and I widen the window past my media query at 1080px, the nav menu disappears and the html tag is left floating 250px to the left, leaving a gap where the menu was. Can I put a command in the jQuery that will close the menu automatically and slide the html tag back over when the screen is wider than 1080px?

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('img.menu.button').click(function() {
    $('html').animate({
    'right' : "250px"}); //moves left 

    $('nav.header-nav').animate({
    'right' : "0px"}); //moves left 


$('img.menu.button').click(function() {
    $('html').animate({
    'right' : "0px"}); //moves right 

    $('nav.header-nav').animate({
    'right' : "-250px" //moves right 



            });
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 0px) 
and (max-width : 1080px) {

img.standard.logo {
height: 38px;
width: 342px;
}

/* RESPONSIVE NAVIGATION MENU */

img.menu.button {
position:relative; 
display:block;
width:25px;
height:25px; 
background-size: 100%;
}

nav.header-nav {
z-index:10;
position:fixed;
top:0px;
right:-250px;
width:250px;
height:100%;
float:right;
margin:0;
padding:0;

background-color:#1D1D1F;
list-style:none; 
box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

Header:

```
<header class="header">
    <!-- LOGOS -->
    <a href="#">
        <img class="standard logo" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Lucie_Averill_Photography_Logo-2.png">
        <img class="white logo" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Lucie_Averill_Photography_Logo_White.png"></a>
    <!-- LOGOS -->
    <img class="menu button" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Menu.png">
    <!-- HEADER NAVIGATION MENU -->
    <nav class="header-nav">
        <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
            <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="menu">
                <li id="menu-item-463">
                    <a href="#">WORK</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-584"><a href="#">LANDSCAPES</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-473"><a href="#">SEASCAPES</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-478"><a href="#">MACRO</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-477"><a href="#">CITIES</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-475"><a href="#">LONG EXPOSURE</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-480"><a href="#">MISCELLANEOUS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-10"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-464"><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-923">
                    <a href="#">SOCIAL</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-11"><a target="_blank" href="#">FACEBOOK</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-924"><a href="#">INSTAGRAM</a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-15"><a target="_blank" href="#">FLICKR</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-14"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by html tag?  Couldl you add a screen grab or something that might help more, no worries i can view the link

Comment: You seem to have two event handlers on the same elements that do opposite things, canceling each other out ?

Comment: Hi Simon, sorry for not being clear – I mean the <html> </html> that contains all the divs in my site. I've set it so that the javascript pushes it over to the left, along with my menu

Comment: @adeneo – Yes, this seems to be the case. The reason I added this was so I could shut the menu after opening it. I'd like to be able to click the button again to close it. It works, but only once.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your second issue, but let me know if my answer solves it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set u pa css class to use then the jQuery toggle class method. First of all i would not use the html part, i would add a main container div to controlthe site etc.

Here is a more in depth link to a working version: [Click here](http://codepen.io/simondavies/pen/bEmJvm)

```
<div class="menu-wrapper">
  <a href="">link</a>
</div>

<div class="main-container">
  <header>Hello
    <button id="menu-btn">MENU</button>
  </header>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
padding:0; 
  margin:0;
}

.main-container {
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width:100%;
  height: auto;
  background: grey;
  transition: all 800ms;
}

header {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  postion: relative;
  height:40px;
 }
#menu-btn {
   padding: 5px 8px;;
  position: relative;
  right: 10px;
  top: 2px;
  float: right;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 800ms, color 800ms;
}
#menu-btn:hover {
  background: white;
  color: black;
 }
.menu-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  right: -250px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 250px;
  background: red;
  z-index:2000;
  transition: all 800ms;
}
.main-container.open {
  right: 250px;
}
.menu-wrapper.open {
  right: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$('#menu-btn').on('click', function(evt){
   evt.preventDefault();
   $('.main-container,.menu-wrapper').toggleClass('open');
 })

//-- check for browser resize
$(window).resize(function() {
  var scrWidth = $(window).width();
  //-- lets remvoe class if screen goes beyond mobile with
  if(scrWidth > 1080) {
      $('.main-container,.menu-wrapper').removeClass('open');
  }

 });
```

Comment: Hi Simon, I can't get that to work, and yet it's not showing any errors in the console. I added the main container div just after the <body> in the header and just before the </body> in the footer

Comment: try without the min container for now an use what you have so far. Also have you added content to the main-container css. eg: position: relative;

Comment: I think I've managed to get this to work – The only issue is that the transition CSS doesn't seem to be havng any effect so both the nav menu and the container (<html>) just dart really quickly from right to left. Do you know how I could fix this?

Comment: have a look at adding transition prefixes, might be a browser thing http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/

Comment: Thanks, could I ask one last question? The srcWidth rule in the javascript works when you open the menu and stretch the browser out, but for some reason when you drag it back down past 1080px, the menu automatically opens again rather than showing you the button.

Comment: mmm! i have added that to my codepen and it seem ok ton there? It could mean its nor removing the open class name though

Comment: Thanks Simon, I think I've cracked it. I was putting the transition css in the .open classes instead of the primary ones

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify by creating a class for the nav being open, to be toggled in jQuery. Set the `width: 0` instead of using a negative value for `right` (this should take care of your second issue (if I understand it correctly), and use a CSS transition to animate the width.

The full-width looks a bit odd, but it seems to be out of the scope of your question. You could set CSS rules to display it how you wish with media queries. Also, I would advise against using jQuery to do anything responsive in this case, it seems rather unnecessary.

I've also set `white-space: nowrap` on the .header-nav element so that the elements don't end up changing wrapped lines during the toggle.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rplittle/bjfwf2o5/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('img.menu.button').click(function() {
    $('nav.header-nav').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1080px) {
  img.standard.logo {
    height: 38px;
    width: 342px;
  }
  /* RESPONSIVE NAVIGATION MENU */
  img.menu.button {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-size: 100%;
  }
  nav.header-nav {
    /* added rules */
    transition: width .5s ease-in-out;
    white-space: nowrap;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #1D1D1F;
    list-style: none;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  nav.header-nav.open {
    /* added */
    width: 250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
  <!-- LOGOS -->
  <a href="#">
    <img class="standard logo" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Lucie_Averill_Photography_Logo-2.png">
    <img class="white logo" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Lucie_Averill_Photography_Logo_White.png">
  </a>
  <!-- LOGOS -->
  <img class="menu button" src="http://www.lucieaverillphotography.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Menu.png">
  <!-- HEADER NAVIGATION MENU -->
  <nav class="header-nav">
    <div class="menu-header-menu-container">
      <ul id="menu-header-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-463">
          <a href="#">WORK</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-584"><a href="#">LANDSCAPES</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-473"><a href="#">SEASCAPES</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-478"><a href="#">MACRO</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-477"><a href="#">CITIES</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-475"><a href="#">LONG EXPOSURE</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-480"><a href="#">MISCELLANEOUS</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-10"><a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-464"><a href="#">SHOP</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-923">
          <a href="#">SOCIAL</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-11"><a target="_blank" href="#">FACEBOOK</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-924"><a href="#">INSTAGRAM</a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-15"><a target="_blank" href="#">FLICKR</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-14"><a href="#">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your reply – this looks like it will work,  but is there a way of getting the rest of the site to move to the left with the menu? I liked the way that my orginal code made it look as though the menu was pushing everything else to the left of the screen when it opened. The problem I was having is that I couldn't get it to move back when changing the screen size to above 1080px, if the menu was still left open.

Comment: It may not be exactly what you want but hopefully it's enough to get the idea and you can edit the CSS to your preference